# 3 Levels of Authentication / Middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-middleware

**Scenario**

Im building an application that offers 3 levels of paid services but im not sure how to go about coding the 3 level functionality.

So for example if my app allowed users to post content to a page, and the 3 levels allowed you to post 1,5 and 10 times a month would i just set up a database that stores the data and then create Middleware to check the amount of times posted / the users post level etc. Im just not 100% certain im going about this right and was wondering if laravel offered any alternatives that i may have overlooked.

**Question**

Should I use middleware to control user levels or does laravel offer alternative and more specific methods?

Comment: Laravel Authorizations with policies and gates. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Comment: @EddyTheDove This is good and answers my question on alternatives but i wouldnt know how to start implementing this

Comment: Well, middlewares still work. Just your question was about `alternative and more specific methods`. So if you think it's too complicated for you, everything is well, middleware are just as effective. Si t'as besoin d'un petit example, je peux bien te le montrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing user roles which correspond to each membership level (i.e. the first role could be 'basic user', the second role could be 'intermediate user', and the third role could be 'advanced user') if you don't want to go with the suggested policies route. Roles can be set up in Laravel using existing packages such as [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and [Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0). In your users table, you should have a user name and role id (foreign key to a role), in your posts table you should have a user id (foreign key to a user) for each post and in your roles table store a post limit against each role (or store it somewhere in the application as a constant/config). When a user attempts to create a new post, you can do a count of all posts they've already submitted, e.g.

`App\User::findById(1)->posts->count();`

or consider using withCount() if you don't want to actually load them. Then follow this up with a check for how many posts the user is limited to, e.g.

`User::findById(1)->role->postLimit`

A comparison between the two should allow you to determine whether or not the user is able to continue posting.

Comment: This is extremely descriptive and just the sort of explanation i was looking for. Laravel is extremely robust and contains so much that i often overlook methods that i should be using